# In practice how well does asymptotic normality of the MLE hold?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, central-limit-theorem, small-sample

There is a lot of theory about asymptotic normality of the MLE and many people use the result to generate confidence intervals given finite sample data. But a key question here is how large a sample size is necessary for asymptotic normality to give reasonable confidence bands and of course this is presumably very dependent on the distribution in question. The first part of my question is whether there any results available about the finite sample performance?

The second part is whether it is possible to do better in the finite sample. I.e. we know that asymptotically,

$$ \sqrt{N} (\hat\theta - \theta_0) \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} N(0, I(\theta_0))$$

and typically we approximate this distribution using $ N(0, \hat i(\hat\theta)) $ where $\hat i(\hat\theta)$ is the estimated Fisher information. Is it possible to derive a distribution for $\hat i(\hat\theta)$ and use this to provide better confidence regions for the MLE? I.e. $\hat i(\hat\theta)$ is random and is not in fact equal to $I(\theta_0)$ so presumably using the asymptotic confidence bands in the finite sample leads to undercoverge.

One thing I thought about was looking an analogy to the one-sample t-statistc where one has $\hat \mu \sim N(0, \sigma^2/N)$. In that setting you can take advantage of the fact that $ \frac{\sqrt{N}\hat\mu}{\hat\sigma}$ is a t-statistic to derive confidence bands for $\mu = \mathbb{E}(\hat \mu)$. So the final part of my question is whether a similar approach would be feasible here.

There seems to be only a limited amount of literature that I could find on the finite sample performance online (as opposed to seemingly 100s of papers on the asymptotic case). In particular this article: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/25/13/027, was helpful, however I would be grateful for other recommendations of similar or more rigorous work if anyone is aware of any.